# Remove Some Files In Folder - Python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to walk through a folder and delete all the files except some of them.The following delivers the appropriate filename to be removed : remfile. The last line however does not remove it, it adds extra backslashes to the remfile(s) address.

How can I rewrite the code to dfine the `C:/tmp` as the root?

```
import os
root='C:/mmp'
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(root):
    for dirname in dirs:
        for filename in files:
            if filename=='keepfile': continue
            remfile=os.path.join(root,dirname,filename)
            os.remove(remfile)
```

Comment: `filename` and `dirname` **are in the same directory**, the file names in `files` should be accessed at `os.path.join(root, filename)`

Answer (score 0):

You should use raw strings and backslash like `root=r'C:\Test'` or double backslash `root='C:\\Test'`.

Now try this:

```
import os
root=r'C:\Test'
for root, dirs,files in os.walk(root):
    for filename in files:
        if filename=='keepfile': continue
        remfile=os.path.join(root,filename)
        print('Removing ' + remfile)
        os.remove(remfile)
```

For my folder hierarchy I got:

```
Removing C:\Test\root_remove1.txt
Removing C:\Test\root_remove2.txt
Removing C:\Test\Folder 1\Folder1_remove1.txt
Removing C:\Test\Folder 1\Folder1_remove2.txt
Removing C:\Test\Folder 2\Folder2_remove1.txt
Removing C:\Test\Folder 2\Folder2_remove2.txt
```

Try adding `print` statements inside your code to verify what is happening inside the loops. It is really helpful sometimes.